# Are there any mirrors for QGIS documentation?

Tags: qgis, documentation

I have tried several times today (July 30, 2012) to connect to www.qgis.org (to get the online documentation). The site seems to be down.

Do you know if there is a mirror to obtain the Lisboa (1.8) full PDF doc?

Comment: It is, but it is also just a temporary problem.

Comment: Had the same problem, while trying to dl a plugin. Hope it works again soon...

Comment: osgeo has docs, but only up to 1.7.2 http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/

Answer (score 1):

You can read the latest documentation online at http://qgis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

The manual for 1.8 isn't ready yet as far as I know because the documentation team is busy improving the overall working environment for authors and translators.